# How do i know what class to reference initially in a javascript module?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, module

I'm working with react and I'm having a hard time figuring out what to reference after I import a module.

for example:

```
npm install example -save
```

then i go to my app.js

```
import xxxx from 'example';
```

How do I know what xxxx is so I can start using the module?

Comment: It depends on what the package is and what it exports...

Comment: so for a package with no documentation, how would i find it?

Comment: What package is it? Have you checked their NPM page? The last resort would be to comb through the source but I'm highly doubt there's no documentation *somewhere*.

Comment: i'm finding quite a few, but here is the most recent frustration: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-wallet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the package is only doing a default export, then you should be able to name it whatever you want in your import and it won't make a difference, i.e.

```
import MyImport from 'package-name';
```

However, if the package is not exporting a default, or has multiple named exports, you can either look at the source code or use `import * as` to iterate through the exports and dump them to a console:

```
import * as e from 'package-name';
console.log(e); // should return anything that's exported e.g. NamedExportA, NamedExportB, etc
```

Once you know the named exports you can then call them by wrapping them in curly braces:

```
import { NamedExportA, NamedExportB } from 'package-name';
```

Comment: thanks! i tested each of these suggestions and they all worked. very helpful.